# Getting linked defects using ALM Rest

Tags: alm, hp-quality-center

Hi Can anyone please help in getting linked defects for test runs in using rest API.
I have tried giving ../defects//defect-links but i am getting bad request error.

Comment: Show us some of your code, so we have an idea of what you are trying.

Comment: Hi Nicolalliias, thanks for replying. I didn't write the code ,just trying the rest APIs of alm to get the data. Can you please suggest the rest api for alm to get the linked defects for test runs. I can see the linked defects in UI but the in the response for the runs API ../project/runs i can't see any field that has link with defects API ../project/defects

Answer (score 0):

I found an API used for getting defect links which is helpful to know where this defects are linked.

https://HOST_NAME/qcbin/rest/domains/DOMAIN_NAME/projects/PROJECT_NAME/defect-links

This API will give you the information of defect_ids and there linked details

Answer (score 0):

Use this rest api for getting defect links

`http://hostname/qcbin/rest/domains/domain_name/projects/project_name/defects/defect_id/defect-links`

This rest api is work on QC and ALM